# The number of different (non-isomorphic) graphs with 4 nodes is:

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

The number of different (non-isomorphic) graphs with 4 nodes is:

A/ 8

B/ 16

C/ 32

D/ 64

Can anyone explain why the correct answer is D please? Thank You

Comment: Why do you think the answer is 64?  That can't possibly be correct; there are only 64 graphs on 4 nodes; so, if there were 64 isomorphism classes, it would mean that you can't find two graphs on four vertices that are non-identical but isomorphic.  That's clearly not the case.

Comment: However, the correct answer here is not actually present; it is $11$.  So, I'm not sure what is going on here.

Comment: how do you get 11 though?

Comment: Break down by the number of edges in the graph; between 0 and 6.  0: one isomorphism class.  1: one isomorphism class.  2: two classes: the edges either touch or don't.  3: three classes: a triangle, a path of length three, or a tree with one vertex of degree 3 and the rest degree 1.  4: two classes, one is a square and the other is a triangle with an edge coming off.  5: one class (just pick an edge to be missing).  6: one graph.

Answer (score 1):

Your result is consistent with labelled nodes, but not with unlabelled nodes.

For labelled nodes, consider that the [complete graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) $K_4$ has $6$ edges. Then possible graphs are the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of those $6$ elements - each edge may be either present or absent independent of the other edges, giving a total of $2^6=64$ alternatives.

For unlabelled nodes, however, as an example there are not $6$ different $5$-edge graphs on $4$ nodes, but only one. The total of $11$ options, to isomorphism, are shown graphically on the [Wolfram page on simple graphs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleGraph.html).